# Local asymptotically stability at a non derivable equilibrium point

Tags: dynamical-systems

Given $\alpha , \beta > 0$ we define $$f(x)=  \begin{cases}
             \alpha x & x \geq 0 \\
              -\beta x & x <0 \\
             \end{cases}$$

It´s obvious that $p=0$ is a fixed point of the system $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, I´m having problems to get the conditions for $\alpha , \beta > 0$ such p is an locally asymptotically stable point.

Well, I see clearly that they should be lower than $1$, but I cannot use the derivative criterium because $f$ is not derivable at $0$, how I can prove this formally? (probably with the definition, but I cannot see)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\beta>0$ then $f(x_n) \ge 0$ after the first iteration, so we can assume that $x_n \ge 0$, so we need only examine $\alpha$.

If $\alpha >1$ then if $x_0 = 1$ we have $x_n = \alpha^n$, which does not converge.

if $\alpha=1$ then if $x_0 = 1$ we have $x_n =1$, so clearly it does not converge to $0$.

If $\alpha \in [0,1)$ then we have $x_n = \alpha^n x_0$ and since $|\alpha|<1$ we see that $x_n \to 0$.

Comment: But f is lipchitz rank less 1 only if $\alpha , \beta$ are less than one, and in the beggining you do not know

Comment: I did not read the question properly, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Nice, ok thankyou, now I notice this little detail, it works by definition.